# Decode Ascii string values from reverse-engineered lua file

Tags: java, python, decoding

I decompiled a **lua** file with unluac and it turns out all the string variables are not readable and are instead `ascii encoded`

```
clues = {
  {
    answer = {
      "\216\173",
      "\216\177",
      "\216\168",
      "\216\167",
      "\216\161"
    },
    text = "\216\173\217\138\217\136\216\167\217\134\032\216\178\216\167\216\173\217\129\032\217\138\216\186\217\138\216\177\032\217\132\217\136\217\134\032\216\172\217\132\216\175\217\135",
    syllables = {
      {"\216\173", "\216\177"},
      {"\216\168", "\216\167"},
      {"\216\161"}
    }
```

How do i go about decoding the whole file `ignoring any non ascii characters` in python or java?

Comment: maybe split the string on each slash, then convert the individual number strings to ints and then to chars. at that moment you can check if the value is below 127 to filter the non-ascii characters.

Comment: What do you mean by 'ascii-encoded'? You can't have it both ASCII-encoded *and* containing non-ASCII characters that you then need to ignore (as proper ASCII-encoded data by definition can't contain data that is not ASCII encodable). Do you mean you need to *decode the numeric escape sequences* perhaps?

Comment: As per my answer below, you don't have ASCII-compatible data, you have Arabic text. Are you *sure* you want to eliminate all non-ASCII data from this? You'd end up with empty strings all round. See my answer below, and [Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space](//stackoverflow.com/q/20078816) for techniques for if you *must* still remove non-ASCII data.

Comment: @MartijnPieters
Thank you for taking the time to write the code below. Excuse my ignorance but i thought it was ascii encoded as i was able to decode it using an online ascii2text decoder `http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/` I'm also a newbie in python, so sorry about that too. I installed python 3 and tried working with the script, but couldn't figure out how to input data(the text file in my case). How can i work with the code? Thanks :) Ps: when i said ignore non ascii chard i meant keep them as is (don't remove them).

Comment: @JawnyThompson: wow, that page is a hell of a mis-nomer. They are not decoding ASCII. They are decoding binary data. The page just *happens* to be using UTF-8 as the encoding, which is why it works. UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII (how ASCII is encoded and how the first 128 Unicode codepoints are encoded to UTF-8 happens to produce the same binary data).

Comment: @JawnyThompson: the code below accepts binary data; if `unluac` produces a string object (`type(obj)` prints `<class 'str'>`), you'll need to encode it to bytes first with `obj.encode('ascii')`. If `unluac` already produces a `bytes` object, you are good to go!

Comment: @JawnyThompson: if I misunderstood and `unluac` produces a file, open the file as binary in Python with `open(filename, 'rb')`, then read the data and pass that to the function I wrote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters
Great, thanks i'll try that now!!

Comment: @MartijnPieters
Just want to mention i tried to work with @hallazzang's answer. It does decode the characters. I had to replace each non encoded digit manually with its dec value `[space --> \032, = --> \61]` then i read my file lines into an array and looped through it decoding and printing each line . Worked like a charm, but when i tried to write the lines to a text file i get an error `f.write(decoded_data) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u062d' : ordinal not in range(128)` each time it writes an arabic character. Code --> [link](https://pastebin.com/dKnYS1Qg)

Comment: @JawnyThompson: you do need to open the output file using a codec that can handle arabic. Use `open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8')` for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters
Great it wrote to the file, but it's not displaying arabic correctly [arabic is RTL], although the console is displaying everything right [console](http://imgh.us/decode.png)

Comment: @MartijnPieters
I'm sorry, looks like sublime itself doesn't support RTL languages. Oh man where do i start learning all about text encoding. Thank you for the great help :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters
I will try out your code, as it will be a hell of a lot easier to work with, as i don't have to do the manual replacement. `Learned a lot today :)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *UTF-8 encoded data*, **not** ASCII, with each byte encoded to a three-digit escape sequence using decimal numbers. The actual text consists mainly of arabic writing.

You need to replace each `\ddd` sequence with the corresponding byte value, then decode as UTF-8. In Python 3:

```
utf8_data = bytes([int(data[i + 1:i + 4]) for i in range(0, len(data), 4)])
print(utf8_data.decode('utf8'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> data = r"\216\173\217\138\217\136\216\167\217\134\032\216\178\216\167\216\173\217\129\032\217\138\216\186\217\138\216\177\032\217\132\217\136\217\134\032\216\172\217\132\216\175\217\135"
>>> utf8_data = bytes([int(data[i + 1:i + 4]) for i in range(0, len(data), 4)])
>>> print(utf8_data.decode('utf8'))
حيوان زاحف يغير لون جلده
```

Google Translate tells me this is *A creepy animal changes the color of its skin* in English.

We can otherwise convert the Lua syntax to JSON using a stack-based parser:

```
import re
import json

def lua_to_python(lua_data):
    return json.loads(''.join(_convert_lua_to_json_chunks(lua_data)))

def _lua_bytes_to_text(data):
    return bytes(
        [int(data[i + 1:i + 4]) for i in range(0, len(data), 4)]
    ).decode('utf8')

def _convert_lua_to_json_chunks(lua_data):
    tokens = re.split(br'(["{},])', lua_data)
    stack = []
    pos_tokens = enumerate(tokens)
    for pos, token in pos_tokens:
        if b'=' in token:
            if not stack:
                # top-level key-value, produce JSON object syntax
                stack.append('}')
                yield '{'
            yield '"{}":'.format(token.strip().rstrip(b' =').decode('utf8'))
        elif token == b'{':
            # array or object?
            next_nonws = next(t for t in tokens[pos + 1:] if t.strip())
            if b'=' in next_nonws:
                stack.append('}')
                yield '{'
            else:
                stack.append(']')
                yield '['
        elif token == b'}':
            yield stack.pop()
        elif token == b'"':
            yield '"'
            for pos, s in pos_tokens:
                if s == b'"':
                    yield '"'
                    break
                yield _lua_bytes_to_text(s)
        else:
            yield token.decode('utf8')
    yield from stack
```

With two additional `}` characters at the end, your data then produces:

```
>>> lua_to_python(lua_data)
{'clues': [{'answer': ['ح', 'ر', 'ب', 'ا', 'ء'], 'text': 'حيوان زاحف يغير لون جلده', 'syllables': [['ح', 'ر'], ['ب', 'ا'], ['ء']]}]}
>>> pprint(lua_to_python(lua_data))
{'clues': [{'answer': ['ح', 'ر', 'ب', 'ا', 'ء'],
            'syllables': [['ح', 'ر'], ['ب', 'ا'], ['ء']],
            'text': 'حيوان زاحف يغير لون جلده'}]}
```

This should give you plenty of options to further process the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

data = '\\216\\173\\217\\138\\217\\136\\216\\167\\217\\134\\032\\216\\178\\216\\167\\216\\173\\217\\129\\032\\217\\138\\216\\186\\217\\138\\216\\177\\032\\217\\132\\217\\136\\217\\134\\032\\216\\172\\217\\132\\216\\175\\217\\135'
decoded_data = re.sub('\\\\(\d{1,3})', lambda x: chr(int(x.group(1))), data).decode('utf-8')

print(repr(decoded_data))
```

Comment: I have thought like that at first, but I found `\168` in the question. Since `8` cannot be in octal numbers, I think these are decimal numbers.

Comment: Yup, I knew I was missing a digit in my reckoning when I made my comment, and just discovered this too.

Comment: At which point this looks like gibberish output (if we presume `text = '..'` to hold actual *text*, and not binary data).

Comment: This code snippet should be run in python 2. I checked it using `data = '\\216\\173\\217\\138\\217\\136\\216\\167\\217\\134\\032\\216\\178\\216\\167\\216\\173\\217\\129\\032\\217\\138\\216\\186\\217\\138\\216\\177\\032\\217\\132\\217\\136\\217\\134\\032\\216\\172\\217\\132\\216\\175\\217\\135'` (which is python string notation of `text` in the question) and the output was `حيوان زاحف يغير لون جلده`.

Comment: It'll depend *on your console encoding* in that case, as you are printing raw bytes to the console or terminal.

Comment: In other words, this is not ASCII data.

Comment: Well, yes, output above was utf-8 encoded data. I'll change my code